# how to display array data in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The following is the array that I made

```
Array
(
    [status] => sukses
    [title] => Xiaomi Mi 9X
    [img] => 9-.jpg
    [hits] => Array
        (
            [hits] => 01-251979
        )
    [suka] => Array
        (
            [suka] => 37
        )
    [data] => Array
        (
            [network] => Array
                (
                    [technology] => ok
                    [2g_bands] => ok
                    [3g_bands] => ok 
                    [4g_bands] =>  ok
                    [speed] => ok
                )
)
```

The following is the PHP Foreach Loop that I made

```
    $arayok = array($hasiljson);
    echo "<table >";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($binatang); $i++) {
        foreach ($binatang[$i] as $key => $val) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo"<td width='150px'>$key</td>";
          echo"<td width='1500px'>$val</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
            foreach ($val as $keys => $values) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo"<td width='150px'>$key</td>";
                    echo"<td width='1500px'>$val</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                foreach ($values as $keysdata => $valuesdata) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo"<td width='150px'>$keysdata</td>";
                    echo"<td width='150px'>$valuesdata</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</table >";
```

how to display multiple arrays using PHP Foreach Loop correctly, because when I display the data the Array network data appears in the table

Comment: Where are the `tr`, `td` tags if you want to use a table?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava, sorry I forgot to put tr td, I changed it